# Why were Nagios and Ganglia in Ambari 1.7 replaced with Ambari Metrics in Ambari 2.0

Tags: nagios, ambari, ganglia

I am fairly new to ambari and am wondering why Nagios and Ganglia in version 1.7 of ambari were replaced with "ambari metrics" in ambari 2.0+ ?

In terms of:
1- performance
2- features
3- and services

was there any clear advantage ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is only for performance. Refer the JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-5707

Couple of issues with Ambari-metrics,

When you are using Ambari Metrics, ensure that you make it distributed, so that there will not be any bottle-neck.

Ambar-metrics stores the data in HBase and sometimes you may see loging to Ambari UI is very very slow. When you face such issues, then you need to restart the HBase & Ambari Metrics. However, Ambari-metrics is better than Nagios & Ganglia

Comment: Why is it better than Nagios and Ganglia? Also, is Amabari metrics using Nagios under the hood ?

Comment: Ambari Metrics uses a light weight process and write the data to HDFS rather then Linux FS.   Hence it will scale. Please check the Jira, first comment that gives some idea of it.We get rid of the writing to FS and then reading back the data in response to the call from GangliaPropertyProvider, instead we use a lightweight wire protocol to push metrics to a collector service which writes it to a local key-value store (e.g.: LevelDB) as well as to a pluggable Storage service layer.